# Will building android use both my harddrives?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, android

I have two internal drives in my Ubuntu-only laptop. My 250GB SSD has Ubuntu installed on it, and my 320GB HDD has is empty and is mounted as a single partition. My question is, if I do something that requires a lot of disk space, like building android ROMs (400GB recommended by Google), how can I utilize both disks in order to have enough space?

Comment: One method would be to set up an LVM, which you can mount as something like `~/develop`. From there you can use that device-spanning directory as a single entity. The downside is that you will not know at what point the directory will switch from using the SSD to the HDD ... aside from the SSD being out of working space. You will also need to be prepared for file operations that "seem slow" if something is on the HDD but you think it's on the SSD (because of the single directory).